# How to zoom to nearest area on Mapbox?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

This is my code to display a marker pintpointing my current location on the map.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="11" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package app.anta40.com.mapboxdemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private final String MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN =
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    private MapView mapView;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Mapbox.getInstance(this, MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        getLocation();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GOT LOCATION: "+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()
        , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                        .title("Hello!")
                        .snippet("This is your current position :)"));
            }
        });
        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void getLocation(){
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);
        }
        catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So far it works OK. What I want to know is how to zoom to the nearest area of the location? Every time I close and run the app, usually the map by default will zoom to South Atlantic Ocean, so I have to pinch to zoom out and scroll the map. A bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
LatLng pos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
mapboxMap.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos,this.map.getCameraPosition())),
    500
);
```

You can also just set the camera position using `mapboxMap.setCameraPosition` which will not animate it